# File included in .gitignore gets deleted from time to time with no apparent reason

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file ignored with .gitignore, from time to time the file just dissapears.
The file's inclusion in .gitignore is present in all the branches so I don't think switching branches is deleting it.
Any idea what may happen with this?

I think the file was tracked at some point but it's now untracked and ignored because it depends on the environment and each installation needs its own version.
There is no deploy script that may be deleting it.

Edit:
I realized that master's *.gitignore* had global reference `env.php` and staging's *.gitignore* had local reference`subdir/env.php`, so maybe that was the issue.

Comment: An unfortunate side effect of naming a path in `.gitignore` is that Git now feels free to *clobber* the file, i.e., to delete it from the work-tree. Git will do so whenever you tell Git to move from a commit in which the file is present—such as one of the older commits where the file was tracked—to a commit in which it is not present. Git removes the file from the index, its usual fashion, and then—since it's `.gitignore`d—removes it from the work-tree without complaining that this might lose data.

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure that none of the branches that we use anymore are in a state where that file is still tracked and deleted, but in any case, I will just delete this file and create another one with a different name and use that, which will be ignored since the beginning and never tracked, so I hope this solves the problem.

By the way, your comment is as good as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like the file was included in some branches before including the row in the .gitignore
If the archive was committed before adding the exception, it will be there until you remove it explicitly.
Review (and delete) the file from your repository to avoid this problem in the future.

Regards
Andoni

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure that none of the branches that we use anymore are in a state where that file is still tracked and deleted, but in any case, I will just delete this file and create another one with a different name and use that, which will be ignored since the beginning and never tracked, so I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: It sounds ok, let me know if that solved the problem!

Comment: Thanks, look the edit for what I've found. What I did finally is just rename the file so now it's untracked and ignored from the beginning.